# How to check if string contains some string from array and then replace it?

Tags: javascript

I have a message like this:

> "Getting Closer! Only $:is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal away from
>   FREE SHIPPING!"

I need to replace `:is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal` with actual number. Also message can contain others variables like `:cart_total_currently , :cart_total_goal , :cart_products_quantity_currently , :cart_products_quantity_goal , :is_left_to_reach_products_quantity_goal , :link , :button .` 
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't have a lot of such special strings, just loop over them and use `replace`.

Comment: You should create array for the words you want to replace, then do foreach of those word **str.replace(word,number)**

Answer (score 1):

This replaces your variable with '2'.

```
var str = "Getting Closer! Only $:is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal away from FREE SHIPPING!";
var res = str.replace("$:is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal", "2");
```

[JavaScript String replace() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This will replace your `original` string with `number`:

```
var original = "Getting Closer! Only $:is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal away from FREE SHIPPING!";
var number = 1;
var newone = original.replace(/:is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal/g, number);
```

you can also create an array of placeholders and values you want to replace and then reduce it like this:

```
var original = "Getting Closer!"
             + "Only $:is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal away from FREE SHIPPING!"
             + "Additional info: $:link";

var toReplace = [
    { key: ":is_left_to_reach_cart_total_goal", value: "1" },
    { key: ":cart_total_currently", value: "2" },
    { key: ":cart_total_goal", value: "3" },
    { key: ":cart_products_quantity_currently", value: "4" },
    { key: ":cart_products_quantity_goal", value: "5" },
    { key: ":is_left_to_reach_products_quantity_goal", value: "6" },
    { key: ":link", value: "7" },
    { key: ":button", value: "whateverelse" }
];

var result = toReplace.reduce(function(r, item) {
    return r.replace(new RegExp(item.key, "g"), item.value);
}, original);
console.log(result);
```

NOTICE: using **g** flag to replace all occurences of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an object which will have keys that can appear in string and hold their values and replace it using loop. Following is an example:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/ppn6L2c6/)

```js
function splitStr(str, seperator) {
  return str.split(seperator)
}

function main() {
  var str = "Getting Closer! Only $:cart_total_currently , $:cart_total_goal , $:cart_products_quantity_currently , $:cart_products_quantity_goal , $:is_left_to_reach_products_quantity_goal , $:link , $:button away from FREE SHIPPING!";

  var valueObj = {
    "cart_total_currently": 100,
    "cart_total_goal": 200,
    "cart_products_quantity_currently": 2,
    "cart_products_quantity_goal": 5,
    "is_left_to_reach_products_quantity_goal": 3,
    "link": "www.google.com",
    "button": "<a href='www.google.com'>link</a>"
  }

  var arrStr = splitStr(str, '$:');
  var resultStr = replaceStr(arrStr, valueObj);
  console.log(resultStr);
}

function replaceStr(arr, obj) {
 var retStr = "";
 arr.forEach(function(row){
   var key = row.split(" ")[0];
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
     retStr += row.replace(key,obj[key]);
    }
    else{
     retStr += row;
    }
  });
  return retStr;
}
main();
```